# Filter nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How can I filter this kind of array? I want to filter it based on my condition below

[image]

```
let employeeLeaves = isEmployeeLeave;

const calendarDates = value.toString();
const formatCalendarDates = moment(calendarDates).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

const filteredData = employeeLeaves.filter(function(item) {
 return item.startDate == formatCalendarDates;
});

return filteredData;
```

Comment: you know what's better than putting a picture of the data in the question? Putting some data in the question - it looks like you have a nested array, so you'll need to filter the second level array, not the first

Comment: It would be helpful to see a sample of the desired output.  Also, what is the status of your attached code?  Is it not completing, or outputting a different format than you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea:

- flatten the nested array into an simple array
- filter the result from the simple array

**Method I: Quick and concise**

```
const result = [].concat(...input).filter(item =>  item.startDate === formatCalendarDates);
```

**Method II: Using a library (e.g. Ramda) to flatten it**

```
R.flatten(data).filter(item => item.key === 'a');
```

See the live result [here](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1#?const%20data%20%3D%20%5B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20key%3A%20%27a%27%2C%20value%3A%201%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20key%3A%20%27b%27%2C%20value%3A%202%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20key%3A%20%27c%27%2C%20value%3A%203%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20key%3A%20%27a%27%2C%20value%3A%204%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20key%3A%20%27b%27%2C%20value%3A%205%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20key%3A%20%27a%27%2C%20value%3A%206%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20key%3A%20%27b%27%2C%20value%3A%207%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20key%3A%20%27b%27%2C%20value%3A%208%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20key%3A%20%27a%27%2C%20value%3A%209%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20key%3A%20%27c%27%2C%20value%3A%2010%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20key%3A%20%27b%27%2C%20value%3A%2011%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20key%3A%20%27b%27%2C%20value%3A%2012%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20R.flatten%28data%29.filter%28item%20%3D%3E%20item.key%20%3D%3D%3D%20%27a%27%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20).

**Method III: do it manually:**

```js
const data = [ 
        [
            { key: 'a', value: 1 },
            { key: 'b', value: 2 },
            { key: 'c', value: 3 },
            { key: 'a', value: 4 },
            { key: 'b', value: 5 },
            { key: 'a', value: 6 }
        ], [
            { key: 'b', value: 7 },
            { key: 'b', value: 8 },
            { key: 'a', value: 9 }
        ], [
            { key: 'c', value: 10 },
            { key: 'b', value: 11 },
            { key: 'b', value: 12 }
        ]
    ];


const flat = data => {
    let output = [];
    data.map(arr => output = [... arr, ... output]) ;
    return output;
}


const result = flat(data).filter(item => item.key === 'a');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for more info

```js
// Input.
const employees = [[{id: '4930'}], [{id: '4328'}]]

// Predicate.
const matchingIdPredicate = (employee, id) => employee.id === id

// Filter.
const employeesWithMatchingId = employees.flat(1).filter(employee => matchingIdPredicate(employee, '4930'))

// Proof.
console.log('Employees with matching id:', employeesWithMatchingId)
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer. I already got it from the answer of @David